# NameError: global name 'messagebox' is not defined - CONSOLE MODE

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

I've imported tkinter.messagebox, and my program runs smoothly when I F5 and test it on IDLE.
However my program doesn't run on console when a messagebox should be displayed, and I get the error:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1456, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "U:\my documents\6th form\A2\Computing\F454\Code and Prototyping\trackeve
nts.py", line 204, in validation
    messagebox.showerror("Data invalid", "The data you have entered is invalid.
Please make sure you have submitted it correctly.")
NameError: global name 'messagebox' is not defined
```

My importing of messagebox and the section of code if it's needed:

```
import tkinter.messagebox

def validation():
(...)
elif completedValidation == False:
    messagebox.showerror("Data invalid", "The data you have entered is invalid. Please make sure you have submitted it correctly.")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `import tkinter.messagebox`, you have to refer to it as such: with `tkinter.messagebox`. If you want to alias it to just `messagebox`, you need `from tkinter import messagebox`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
#rest of the code and replace the below line
tkMessageBox.showerror("Data invalid", "The data you have entered is invalid. Please make sure you have submitted it correctly.")
```

Comment: Python 3.x and the latest tkinter doesn't use tkMessageBox anymore, as I've found multiple times sadly.

Comment: The above command will only supports in Python2.7. Works at my end.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if the tkinter module is up to date.

```
from tkinter import messagebox
messagebox.showinfo("abc", "def")
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35719094)